# How to find the closest date from array to push into already chosen dates array

Tags: php, arrays, date

```
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:00:00", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:05:00", "duration" => "300");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:10:00", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:25:00", "duration" => "300");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:30:00", "duration" => "600");
function closestDates($array, $date){   
    foreach($array as $day)
         $interval[] = abs(strtotime($date["date"]) - strtotime($day["date"]));
    asort($interval);
    $closest = key($interval);
    $alreadyChosen[] = $array[$closest];
    return $alreadyChosen;
}
$returnedDates = closestDates($dates, array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:00:00", "duration" => "600"));
print_r($returnedDates);

// This returns 
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [date] => 2016-02-18 02:00:00 
        [duration] => 600 
    ) 
)
```

How can I adapt the above function to be able to check through `dates` array and push the next closest date to `alreadyChosen` array based on the duration time.

```
$dates = (
    '0'=> array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:00:00", "duration" => "600"),
    '1'=> array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:05:00", "duration" => "300"),
    '2'=> array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:10:00", "duration" => "600"),
    '3'=> array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:25:00", "duration" => "300"),
    '4'=> array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:30:00", "duration" => "600")
);

// Expected result to be after the checks:
$alreadyChosen = array
(
    '0'=> array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:00:00", "duration" => "600"),
    '1'=> array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:10:00", "duration" => "600"),
    '2'=> array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:25:00", "duration" => "300"),
    '3'=> array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:30:00", "duration" => "600")
);
```

Comment: I believe closestDate function is already working fine....Now how do you want to use $alreadyChosen??? to me, that is not clear in your question

Comment: what do you mean by `doesn't check on duration time`. Also your question mentions two `$alreadyChosen`

Comment: can you please elaborate on your expected output.. I am not able to get it

Comment: @undefined_variable Expected result is to be able to pass a starting date, which would be `2016-02-18 02:00:00` with duration of 600 (10 minutes) based on the duration, find the closest date which would be equal to the end of the duration or greater than the duration. Then so on.....

Comment: @undefined_variable I've updated my question, it should be easier to understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution by doing the following: (I changed alot of things from my question to get it working)

```
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:00:00", "meeting_id" => "1", "class_id" => "10", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:10:00", "meeting_id" => "1", "class_id" => "10", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:20:00", "meeting_id" => "1", "class_id" => "10", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:30:00", "meeting_id" => "1", "class_id" => "10", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:10:00", "meeting_id" => "2", "class_id" => "10", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:25:00", "meeting_id" => "2", "class_id" => "10", "duration" => "300");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:30:00", "meeting_id" => "3", "class_id" => "10", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:40:00", "meeting_id" => "3", "class_id" => "10", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:30:00", "meeting_id" => "4", "class_id" => "11", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:40:00", "meeting_id" => "4", "class_id" => "11", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:50:00", "meeting_id" => "4", "class_id" => "11", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 03:00:00", "meeting_id" => "4", "class_id" => "11", "duration" => "600");

$firstDates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:00:00", "meeting_id" => "1", "class_id" => "10", "duration" => "600");
$firstDates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:10:00", "meeting_id" => "1", "class_id" => "10", "duration" => "600");
$firstDates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:20:00", "meeting_id" => "1", "class_id" => "10", "duration" => "600");
$firstDates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:30:00", "meeting_id" => "1", "class_id" => "10", "duration" => "600");

$children[] = array("id" => 1, "class_id" => "10", "fullname" => "Callum");
$children[] = array("id" => 2, "class_id" => "10", "fullname" => "Daniel");
$children[] = array("id" => 3, "class_id" => "11", "fullname" => "Jake");

function dateExists($array, $child, $date) {
    if (empty($array)) {
        return false;
    }
    $flag = false;
    foreach($array as $value) {
        if ($value['child']['id'] == $child['id'] && $value['meeting']['meeting_id'] === $date['meeting_id']){
            return true;
        }
        if ($value['meeting']['date'] == $date['date']) {
            return true;
        }
        $start = strtotime($value['meeting']['date']);
        $end = $start + $value['meeting']['duration'];
        $ts = strtotime($date['date']);
        if ($ts > $start && $ts < $end) {
            $flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $flag;
}


$results = [];

function buildDates($dates, $children, $key, $firstDate) {
    $temp = [];
    $pickedDates = array();
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        if($firstDate["class_id"] === $child["class_id"]) {
            $temp[] = array('child' => $child, 'meeting' => $firstDate);
            $pickedDates[$firstDate['date']] = $temp;
        }
        break;
    }
    foreach ($dates as $key => $date) {
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if($date["class_id"] === $child["class_id"]) {
                if (!dateExists($temp, $child, $date)) {
                    $temp[] = array('child' => $child, 'meeting' => $date);
                    $pickedDates[$firstDate['date']] = $temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $pickedDates = array($firstDate["date"] => $temp);
}

foreach ($firstDates as $date) {
    $results[] = buildDates($dates, $children, $date);
}

print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get most close date to date what you enter into function and prevent dates what are already picked you could do it like that:

```
function pickMostCloserDate($dateArray, $compareDate, &$pickedDates = array())
{
    $dates = [];  
    foreach($dateArray as $key => $originalDate){
        $date = $date['date'];
        //compare options
        if(!in_array($originalDate, $pickedDates)){
           $dates[$key] = abs(strtotime($compareDate) - strtotime($date));
        }
    }

    asort($dates);

    $dateIndex = array_shift(array_keys($dates));

    array_push($pickedDates, $dateArray[$dateIndex]);
    return $dateArray[$dateIndex];

}
```

This will return most close date and it will add found date to pickedDates so what actualy you have to do is:

```
$pickedDates = [];
$closeDate = pickMostCloserDate($arrayWithDates, '2016-05-05 00:00:00', $pickedDates);
```

echo $closeDate;

//next round to pick date

Hope this helps. Please be aware that I wrote this from head, need to be fixed.

Comment: Hey I've updated my question with more information, it should help you out with what i'm looking for.

Comment: I've updated my answer even more, it should be easier to understand now.

Comment: Hi, Chris this should help you with your problem. Function will pick closer that to specific date and also it will append found date into pickedDates variable. As much as you will call the function the new dates will be picked up.

Comment: Hey, Kamil. Your answer so far gives me exactly what I've already got in my question. Please check my expected result to give yourself an idea of what i'm looking for.

Comment: Chris, I'm not sure if I understand what you want. But as I see the second array have more dates in. What's actually this function does, if you will call the function multiple times. It will append dates into variable $pickedDates. So in this case you could probably put this function into loop to store these dates into that variable. That what I understood what you wanted.

Comment: Kamil let's continue this discussion - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126106/discussion

Comment: I basically want what you have but to have an extra feature of checking inside the `$pickedDates` to make sure that the closest time is equal or greater to the last `$pickedDates` date. But it would also be good to check if a date can fit between two dates already in the `$pickedDates` without the dates and duration overlapping each other. 

Does that make sense?